# WPF DataContext not work but set ItemsSource works

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

Assume I have this code:

```
public class ViewModel {
    public ObservableCollection<string> Items;
}
```

and use it like in code behind

```
public ViewModel MyViewModel = new ViewModel();

public Constructor() {
    this.DataContext = MyViewModel;
}
```

of the following view

```
<ItemsControl x:Name="itemsControl" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Items}">...</ItemsControl>
```

The above code doesn't work as expected. The control is not being populated.

However this works:

```
this.itemsControl.ItemsSource = this.MyViewModel.Items;
```

Can anyone please explain why?

Comment: I don't think so. ViewModel is a class with an ObservableCollection<string> Items

Comment: Can you then clarify the expected and actual behavior. `doesn't work as expected` is too vague.

Comment: Please read the question again. The itemsSource control point to Items property. I just had a typo, thanks.

Comment: Items is an ObservableCollection<string>. Problem is the ItemsSource property not work in XAML but it works in code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Binding can only happen on public properties.

If `Items` is a field, say...

```
public class ViewModel {
    public ObservableCollection<string> Items;
}
```

Then the following wont bind to the field.

```
<ItemsControl x:Name="itemsControl" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Items}">...</ItemsControl>
```

You need to make it a property for the view to be able to see and bind to it.

```
public class ViewModel {
    public ObservableCollection<string> Items {get; set;}
}
```

This is just a simple example. The usually `INotifyPropertyChanged` and the likes still apply.

Comment: Thanks, in my code the Items property is missing { get; set; }. Added then it works :)

Comment: @trinvh Then that meant it was a **field** and by adding the `{ get; set; }` you made it into a bindable **property**.